# Firebase Hosting deploy gives HTTP Error 401

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm currently having an issue with Firebase hosting.
After i run `firebase deploy`, I get the following error:

> === Deploying to '[my project]'...
>
> i  deploying hosting 
>   i  hosting: preparing . directory for upload... 
>   ✔ hosting: 55 files uploaded successfully
>
> Error: HTTP Error: 400, Precondition check failed. 
>   Deploy completed!

In Firebase Hosting Console, the app is correctly deployed, but I can't select the latest version as the current one.

Did someone get the same error?
Thank you!

[image: Error I get]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there are issues with the firebase hosting. Therefore other people are also having this issue.

To check for updates about the problem, please check this link: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Hosting/18002

> Feb 01, 2018    02:07
>   We're investigating an issue with Firebase Hosting and will provide more information by 2:30 AM.

---

> Feb 01, 2018    02:30
>   We are experiencing an issue with Firebase Hosting where 503/504 errors are being returned upon accessing the domains. For everyone who is affected, we apologize for any inconvenience you may be experiencing.

The issue has been recognized and is being investigated.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm having a lot off issues with Firebase since last week (Firestore was unavailable, now hosting doesn't work well).

I hope that it will be solved soon :(